# Iterating collections CakePHP 3

Tags: php, collections, iteration, cakephp-3.0

I am having an array that I make a collection out of it with CakePHP 3 then I use match to extract a new collection containing only the elements that id=2.
What I am unable to understand is after I use match if I use **each** to iterate with my original collection i see the element with id=2. \

Shouldn't it be removed from the original collection ?

How can I iterate my new collection cause **each, compile, foreach** are not working, and when I use debug all I get is

```
\src\Controller\ComlibsController.php (line 51)
object(Cake\Collection\Collection) {

'count' => (int) 0

}
```

The collection code id :

```
           //get the current answer and remove it from the query array
    $mycollection = new Collection($query[0]['answers']);
          $answer = $mycollection->match(['answers.id' => $theid]);
```

Cookbook is not as simple as they claimed.

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Performing a match on a collection returns a new collection with the elements that match, but it doesn't alter the original collection in any way.
2. When you're creating your collection, you're specifying the `['answers']` key, which means that won't be part of the path any more for elements in the collection. You will therefore simply want to do `->match(['id' => $theid])` to find the matches.